# Background image for navbar not fitting properly

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My navbar has a padding top and bottom of 70px. Height wise it's a bigger navbar than usual. I'm trying to use a photo to fill this entire space as a background for my navbar but it fills only a very tiny space right down the middle and the rest of the navbar stays white. How can I fill the entire space of my navbar with my photo?

```css
.navbar {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar-inner{
  background-image: url('../img/mixer.jpg');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.navbar-default {
 padding-top: 70px;
 padding-bottom: 70px;
 border-color: #1E1E20; /*light black*/
}

.navbar-brand {
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 20px;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

ul.nav a { 
 color: #1abc9c !important; /*teal*/
}

ul.nav a:hover,
ul.nav a:focus { 
 color: #7b7b7b !important; /*lightest grey*/ 
} 

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
 border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-inner">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">KEN COOPER</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shows</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div> <!-- end navar collapse -->
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.navbar {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
      background: url('http://vpnhotlist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/image.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/8979/